# How to make binding between the ">" and "</"?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add binding right to content of a control.

```
 <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                    ???? {Binding Title} ???
  </Hyperlink>
```

But how can I do that? I tried this:

```
 <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" Content="{Binding Title}" />
```

but it gave me an error because there was no property `Content`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
 <Hyperlink
     NavigateUri="{Binding Link}"
     RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">

     <Run Text="{Binding Title}" />

 </Hyperlink>
```